# Run Custom Script after Publish to file system Visual Studio 2017

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, publish

I created publish profile that publish to File System, and I need to run custom script after publish from context menu of visual studio 2017 is finished.

Comment: I think you can just create a custom target in `xxxx.csproj` file which contains a command to run `xxx.ps1`.

Answer (score 4):

> Run Custom Script after Publish to file system Visual Studio 2017

I think you can just create a custom target in `xxxx.csproj` file or `xxxxxx.pubxml` file.

Just like this:

```
 <Target Name="RunCustomScript" AfterTargets="GatherAllFilesToPublish">
 <Exec Command="xxxx\xxxx.ps1" />
  </Target>
```

You can set this target in `xxxx.csproj`or `xxxx.pubxml`.

**Note** that `GatherAllFilesToPublish` is one of the publish process's system target and when this custom target depends on `GatherAllFilesToPublish`, it will always run and execute the script adter publish process.

**Update 1**

Sorry for not understanding your requirements in time. I assume you want to do some operation such as copying when all the imported files are published into the publish folder.

**In general**, this step does not belong to any system targets and MS has confirmed, that when publishing to file system they don't have any target to launch after that.

> "We currently do not support executing custom targets after publish
>   from VS for the file system protocol."

However we can try this way:

**1)** create a custom target which uses `AfterTargets="CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage" (runs just before the files are copied to the publish location)`.

**2)** In custom target, use asynchronous execution `AsyncExec` of the script to ensure that the publish file to publish folder operation is executed while the script is running.

**3)** After that, in the script, the execution of the content is delayed by **5 seconds** (the time can be changed according to the specific release time of the packaged file) to ensure that the script content is executed after the system publishes all the files.

**Step**

**1)** install the nuget package called [MSBuild.Extension.Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuild.Extension.Pack/) into your project.

**2)** create the custom target and use its `AsyncExec` to execute your script.

```
<Target Name="RunCustomScript" AfterTargets="GatherAllFilesToPublish">
    <AsyncExec command="powershell.exe C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxx.ps1" />
</Target>
```

**3)** Open your script, please add this on the top of all the content which means that sleep for 5 seconds before executing the contents of the script.

```
Start-Sleep -s 5  // 5 means 5 seconds
```

Therefore, the script will executes after all the files are published into the `publish` folder.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Sorry sir but this Target is executed before the publish finished on visual studio 2019